# What does the alternate ending to Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle entail?

Tags: production, jumanji, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

According to *[The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/jumanji-welcome-jungle-alternate-endings-revealed-1069469)*,  alternate endings to *Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle* were considered.

> And when viewers watched Dwayne Johnson's character contemplate staying in the game at the end, he actually almost did. Says actress Karen Gillan, who stars alongside Johnson and Jonas as well as Kevin Hart and Jack Black, "In previous versions there was more of that where [Spencer] wanted to stay in the game with Martha. We made way more of that."

Did any of this make it to principal photography? Or were these just versions of the script that were never actually filmed?

Comment: The wording by the actress in your quote makes it seem to me that they did film more.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot indeed, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kmLkHD9KyiE

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, yeah, that's all Google yielded, stuff like that.

Comment: The quote "made way more of that" would suggest it was a bigger part of the story, not that it necessarily ended differently.